# Como excluir elementos de uma coleção jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Por exemplo: Eu quero dar um `.fadeOut()` em todo `body`, mas com exceção de algum elemento, como uma div. Isso pode ser feito? Como?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Com jQuery você pode usar a função [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/). Ela permite que você selecione um grupo maior de objetos e retire deles os que você não quer.

Por exemplo:

```
// seleciona todas as divs exceto as que tem a classe classe1
$('div').not('.classe1') 
// seleciona todas as `<option>` exceto as selecionadas
$('option').not(':selected')
```

Comment: Obrigado, Ricardo!

Comment: valeu mano, dessa eu não sabia!!